# How can I draw power from adapter plug without damaging it?

Tags: wiring

Sorry for the vague title for I am not sure how to precisely describe it.

Basically I need a 12V power source and I plan to draw the power from an AC to 12VDC power adapter. The output of that adapter is a female plug and the unit comes with a few interchangeable heads. The plug looks like this:
[image]

The diameter of the holes is about 1.5 to 2 mm.

I know I can simply cut the wire between the plug and the adapter but before I do that I wonder if there is other way to leave everything undamaged?

The current I want to draw is less than 1 amp.

Comment: Buy the right head. The connector is a standard Adaptaplug, check radioshack.

Comment: @Passerby What I need is not the head, but thanks for letting me know the name!

Comment: There are always a couple of those heads you will never use. Pick one and hack it, if you don't want to buy anything else.

Comment: If you have a soldering iron, you could also buy on-cable DC "jacks" with pin to mate the barrel connector[s] that come with your kit, e.g [these](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-21-x-5mm-dc-power-line-socket-jk11m). Or if can't solder get the one indicated by Roger Rowland below, which less reliable in the long run (and more prone to shorting if you're not careful). Makes sure you see picture or better buy in person because the male/female terminology is really confused by sellers when it comes to [these babies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio Shack/The Source sells extension cables that fit that. Buy one and cut that up instead, inserting your device in between.

Comment: There is no Radio Shack here...gotta go to local electronics stores. Thank you!

Comment: @anetworknoobie: "Adaptaplug" is Radioshack brand (and not really a standard). Outside US, the name Adaptaplug may be unheard of... even if similarly looking connectors are found on  other "universal" power supplies sold around the world. Searching for "Adaptaplug"  on RS or Farnell -> 0 hits.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the correct 2.1mm interchangeable head on that adapter and then [plug it into one of these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Female-DC-Power-adapter-2-1mm-jack-to-screw-terminal-block-/161378409853?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368). No need to cut anything!

[image: dc]

Comment: A word of caution with these from my own experience: they tend to be a bit more short-prone than soldered variants. The combination of no strain relief and straight clamps biting on the wires tend to result in "mustaches" from severed conductors on (multistrand) wires after moving them around a bit... which in turn can touch the other conductor. You can't see in this picture but they have fairly large exposed metal surfaces on the green end where the wires go in. Long story short, one of these shorted a (sealed) transformer I had, which I then had to crack open and replace its thermal fuse.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Yes, actually I agree. The version I have has the push-and-release spring terminals, which I found work best with DuPont jumper wires, which have a pin-like end.

Comment: Hmm. Actually I ended up with a similar solution. I bought a spliter which has female plug to one of the heads on input, and two male plug on output, and I cut one of the output.